# Влияние альфа-версии на продвижение приложения в Google-play

Tags: android

При публикации приложения в Google-play, насколько мне известно, оно попадает в раздел "новые" или что-то типа того. Это, так сказать, бонус от Googl-а на продвижение нового приложения, который действует около двух недель с момента публикации. Вопрос в чем: если я опубликую только альфа или бета-версию своего приложения, чтобы его протестировать, включится ли этот бонус в момент ее публикации или он включается только в момент публикации уже рабочей версии?

А то хочется и проверить свое приложение до релиза, и при этом не потерять этот бонус к продвижению.

Comment: Там же не две недели, а месяц кстати.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Альфа-, бета- версии только для тестирования. В раздел "новые" приложение попадает только после публикации первой релизной версии.